# How many outlets can a 20amp breaker have?

Tags: receptacle, circuit-breaker

Using 12-2 and installing all new outlets, wire, and breaker.

Comment: What are the outlets for?  Can only use up to 20 amps, so possible to use 100 outlets for low power LED lights.  A single double outlet is  pushing it if plugging in a kettle and toaster at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, no limit in the NEC, though other restrictions may come into play. For example, bathroom circuits are limited to bathrooms and kitchen circuits are limited to kitchens (and certain related areas). But for general purpose circuits (living room, bedrooms, etc.) there is no set limit.

However, there are some jurisdictions with specific limits. For example, Canada has a limit of 16 or 20 - see [this article](https://www.electrofed.com/2021/03/2021-changes-in-the-canadian-electrical-code-2103-circuit-loading/) for details.